# regular expression for extracting everything after ":" of a command line output in bash

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a bash script that currently stores a command line output into a variable. I want to perform regular expression to extract everything after the last colon (`:`).

This is my code:

```
line="$(command line)"
echo "$line" | awk '/[^:]+$/'
```

This unfortunately doesn't work. How should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU bash and its [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32):

```
line="root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash"
echo "${line/*:/}"
```

Output:

```
/bin/bash
```

---

With GNU bash and regex:

```
line="root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash"
[[ $line =~ ([^:]*)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Output:

```
/bin/bash
```

Comment: Alternatively: `echo "${line##*:}"` - https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk with -F option to specify ":" as the field separator.

To be able to print the last one, use NF which refers to the number of fields of the current record, so printing $NF means printing everything after the last ":".

your commands should look like this -

```
line="$(echo $PATH)"
echo $line | awk -F: '{print $NF}'
```

`echo $PATH` is example of any command with output contain ":"

You can lean more about awk [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-awk1/).