# Shell string processing using regex and extract words based on delimiters

Tags: regex, string, bash, shell

I have previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798574/regular-expression-for-extracting-everything-after-of-a-command-line-output) about using regex to get the string from the last colon. I have received some answers though I don't quite know how to integrate it with the rest of the program. I have a command line that will return an output in the form of `st:st:st:st1-st2-st3-st4-...stn`, I want to strip out st1, st2, st3...stn and write them in a text file like `st1 \n "st2 \n...."stn \n`.

I know I can use `while IFS:-` to extract the strings I want but how to get rid of the string before the last colon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get rid of the string before the last colon?

Use prefix removal:

```
$ str='st:st:st:st1-st2-st3-st4-...stn'
$ echo "${str##*:}"
st1-st2-st3-st4-...stn
```

`${str##*:}` returns the string `$str` after having removed the longest match that starts from the beginning and ends with a `:`.

#### Documentation

From `man bash`:

> ${parameter#word}
>     ${parameter##word}
>      **Remove  matching prefix pattern.**  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in pathname expansion.  If the pattern
>   matches
>             the beginning of the value of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of  parameter  with  the  shortest
>             matching  pattern (the ''#'' case) or the longest matching pattern (the ''##'' case) deleted.  If parameter is @ or *, the
>   pattern
>             removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.  If  parameter  is  an
>             array  variable  subscripted  with  @  or *, the pattern removal operation is applied to each member of the array in turn, and
>   the
>    expansion is the resultant list.

Comment: What's the meaning of ##*?

Comment: In this context, it means 'remove the longest matching prefix.'